# Postman AWS Signature for SP-API not working

Tags: postman, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api, aws-signature

I am trying out SP-API catalog items API from postman. Trying to signing request using `AWS Signature` provided in postman. But getting the following error.
[image]

Headers used
[image]

Getting the following error

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. ",
        "code": "InvalidSignature"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "Service name" to "execute-api"

Answer (score 0):

You have entered wrong data in [Service Name]

**Set execute-api in Service Name**

[image]

[amz-sp-api](/questions/tagged/amz-sp-api)  [postman](/questions/tagged/postman)   [mayurpathak](/questions/tagged/mayurpathak)  [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon)

Answer (score 0):

Set your your SecretKey = awsSecretAccessKey you recieved when you authorized the app.